# Yandex Maps Api Как нарисовать круг с закрашенной внешней областью

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как нарисовать круг с закрашенной внешней областью?

1. рисуем круга радиуса R на карте
2. Закрашиваем область за кругом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно нарисовать прямоугольник на всю планету и сделать в нем "дырку", посчитано при помощи [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/).

Для того чтобы круг выглядел кругом на любой широте - необходимо учесть искажение проекции Меркатора `Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var center = [59.95, 30.3];
var merc = Math.cos(center[0]*Math.PI/180)*0.85; 
var r = 15;
var circle = turf.ellipse(center, r*merc, r, {
  steps: 360, 
  units: 'kilometers'
});

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: center,
    zoom: 10
  });
  
  map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Polygon([
    [
      [-180, -90],
      [ 180, -90],
      [ 180,  90],
      [-180,  90],
      [-180, -90]
    ],
    circle.geometry.coordinates[0]
  ]));
}
```

```css
html,body,#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: У меня почему-то не получается закрасить весь мир. Если сделать зум = 0, то будет полоска. где-то в пол мира по ширине и в бесконечности по высоте.

Comment: @Masquitos есть скрин?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/12Slk3gA2-Ilqg в твоем примере та же проблема. умнешь скрин по максимом

Comment: @Masquitos я просто сейчас с телефоном, а если поменять местами 180 и 90?

Comment: поменял. в итоге полоска бесконечная по высоте.